# Многоязычные интерфейсы

Tags: php, javascript

Есть желание внедрить в свою систему многоязычный интерфейс, морока конечно еще та, но хотелось бы услышать мнение экспертов какие способы из известных понравились в практике, а какие нет, или просто идеи. Способов много, иногда даже формируют что-то на подобии словаря, и потом складывают символы, свой язык почти что. Но мне это кажется не слишком удобным, да и экономия памяти весьма сомнительна. Но все-таки, за любые хорошие идеи непременно натыкаю плюсов :)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, возможно, сложный, но с быстродействием проблем быть не должно. Если это именно интерфейс и данные переводить не надо либо не в рамках этой задачи, можно компилить шаблоны под язык.

То есть, допустим, имеем такой шаблон:

```
<? if (!defined('ALL_OK')) die('Access denied'); ?>
<ul id="adminmenu">
  <li><a href="/admin/">Администрирование</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/data/">Данные</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/users/">Пользователи</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/?exit=1">Выход</a></li>
</ul>
<? echo $this->someText; ?>
```

Теперь ищем в коде шаблонизатора подключение шаблона и меняем его на примерно такой

```
//$template = ROOT.'/templates/admin/menu.tpl.php';
$lang = $_SESSION['LANG'];
$template = compileTemplate($lang, ROOT.'/templates/admin/menu.tpl.php', !empty($_GET['clearcache'])); // собираем шаблон, учитывая необходимость сброса кэша при отладке
// и далее как обычно.
```

Ковыряем шаблон:

```
<? if (!defined('ALL_OK')) die('Access denied'); ?>
<ul id="adminmenu">
  <li><a href="/admin/">[[L:menu-admin]]</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/data/">[[L:menu-data]]</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/users/">[[L:menu-users]]</a></li>
  <li><a href="/admin/?exit=1">[[L:menu-exit]]</a></li>
</ul>
<? echo $this->someText; ?>
```

Функция:

```
function compileTemplate($lang, $template, $forceUpdate = false) {
  $dest = ROOT.'/lng/'.$lang.'/'.md5($template).'.tpl.php';
  if (file_exists($dest) && !$forceUpdate)
    return $dest; // если файл уже есть и обновлять не надо, выходим.
  $tplText = file_get_contents($template);
  $langArray = array('menu-admin' => 'Администрирование'); // подгружаем ассоциативный массив с языком
  foreach ($langArray as $code => $value)
    if (strpos($tplText, '[[L:'.$code.']]') !== false)
      $tplText = str_replace('[[L:'.$code.']]', $value, $tplText); // заменяем все метки и возвращаем готовый шаблон
  file_put_contents($dest, $tplText);
  return $dest;
  }
```

Таким образом файлы будут собраны "навечно", php-код в них от этого не пострадает. Быстродействие на максимуме, расход памяти на минимуме. Хотя да, это надо аккуратно использовать и не пускать манагеров делать шаблоны и переводить ( `... echo '[[L:menu]]'; ...` при `"menu" => "<div style='float: left'>text</div>"` уронит код).

---

А вот, например, аффтары джумлы вообще не парились - на каждый запуск скрипта парсится несколько .ini и запиливаются в сессию) Иногда метра по 2 набирается.

**UPD** можно еще по-другому подойти к замене меток. Если данные хранить в базе, то можно сначала регуляркой получить все метки

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[L\:([^\]]+)\]\]/', $tplText, $matches);
// собрать из $matches адекватный массив $codes и потом 
// доставать их из базы одним запросом
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM lng WHERE (`lang_id`="'.$lang.'" AND `word_id` IN ("'.implode('", "', $codes).'"));');
// и уже с ним бегать по шаблону и заменять.
// Это, типа, оптимизация, если что)
```

Comment: Этот вариант мне нравится и я именно в таком направлении и был намерен работать. Но на всякий случай хотел переспросить может наука придумала что-то еще более интересное :)

Comment: Проблема только в том что это больше расчитано на статику. При динамических шаблонах придется компилировать каждый раз. +опять таки подгружаем переводы из базы при каждом запросе. Но по другому и не выйдет

Comment: Ну так может стоит смешать gettext, вместе с этим способом. Чтобы если в шаблон вставили переменную, собираем шаблон с этой переменной наглухо. Если что-то в пхп крутится то там используем gettext? Должно по идее быть юзабильно.

Comment: @shurik, а почему на статику? Шаблон такого вида тоже норм соберется

    <? if ($user->id > 0) { ?>
      <a href="/profile/">[[L:profile]]</a>
    <? } else { ?>
      <a href="/auth/">[[L:authorize]]</a>
    <? } ?>

И не надо будет каждый раз компилить) Я чего-то не заметил?

Comment: допустим в тексте есть строка: 

'we got %d items from %s' как вы это переводить будете ? :)

Comment: я за 5 лет *сам* ни разу не пользовался printf) И ни разу не видел ситуации, где нельзя вынести из него текст)) Ну и 1) в шаблон запиливаются id сообщений, т.е. `'we got %d items from %s'` можно записать в базу, 2) в совсем крайнем случае есть heredoc

    echo printf(
    <<<STR
    [[L:we-got]] %d [[L:items-from]] %s
    STR
    , $a, $b);

Answer (score 3):

В PHP есть поддержка стандартного unix-ового механизма локализации приложений [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), об этом можно [узнать подробнее](http://www.tvysoftware.com/library/gettext-php_multilng.html). Неплохой обзор чего может gettext есть в Википедии: [ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомлюсь, слышал когда-то давно об этом, но чето даже с головы вылетело.

Answer (score 2):

самый простой способ - использовать какую-то функцию для получения переведенного текста.

например:

```
function _($key)
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    $row = mysql_get('select value from i18n where key='.quote($key).' and lang='.quote($lang));
    if ($row !== false) {
        return $row['value']
    }
    mysql_insert('i18n', array('value' => '{'.$key.'}', 'key' => $key, 'lang' => $lang));
    return '{'.$key.'}';
}
```

решение спорное так как можно применить кеширование (что бы на каждый перевод не лезть в базу и т.д)

Сами переводы осуществляются путем замены данных в таблице +сброс кеша.

Дерзайте, фантазируйте :)
ЗЫ: можно также пропустить полученный результат через sprintf что бы была возможность форматирования динамических строк. аля: _('we got %d items from %s', 100, 'USA');
Ну и разумеется что и в переводе должны быть % ("Мы получили % предметов из %")

Comment: Какое-то ощущение что ветром от Drupal повеяло ))). Стремно как-то за каждым словом да в базу. Часто такой метод практикуется?

Comment: я же и говорю что бы не лезть в базу каждый раз - используйте кеширование :)

>> Часто такой метод практикуется?

да как бы вам это сказать, фундаментальных принципов переводов не так уже и много...

ЗЫ: друпал ни разу не использовал и даже не смотрел в его сторону :)

Comment: Та я понял про кеширование ))) гыгы. Но кеш тоже штука скользкая особенно когда его много. Ладно спасибо буду прорабатывать вариант в живую.

Answer (score 1):

А я бы делал интереснее :)

- Создал бы, например, CSV, либо, еще лучше, json файл.
- В сайле создал бы объект типа

lang: {
        label: "Лэйб",
        menu: "Меню",
        оptions: "Опции",
        etc......
        }

- Далее, при формировании страницы я бы подсовывал этот json к ней.
- Сделал бы глобальную функцию, например, translate, в которой бы описал какому элементу присвоить значение из объекта lans.

Плюсы:

1 Моментальная смена интерфейса.

2 Замечательно работает кэширование таких объектов

Минусов не нашел :)

P.S.  *Как показывает практика: Если Вы будете говорить, что это сильно нагрузить страницу - ошибаетесь :) Не нагрузить совершенно. Гораздо большая нагрузка на сервер будет отписывать каждый раз то или иное значение в зависимости от перевода + кэширование стандартного html контента будет затруднено.*

Comment: А то что объект будет метр весить - это хорошо?)

Comment: Ну так в любом случае будет расход памяти.

Comment: Частный случай кеширования из базы ;)

Кешировать можно в файле json формата, либо вообще serialize

ЗЫ: метр ? Ну это должен быть нууууу очеееень большой сайт.

Comment: По-моему, вы пытаетесь заново придумать gettext :)